# How to handle unicode file path in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, path, nsstring, copy, unicode-string

I am developing an app which supports viewing of document files. Problem is that I have a file whose name is in Urdu language.
When I select "Open in MyApp" option from Mail app, the file is copied into Inbox folder. I want to copy this file to some other folder. I get the file path from launchOption dictionary and pass it to copyItemAt method. Code for getting file path is

```
NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
NSString *urlStr = [url absoluteString];
```

And code for copying the file is

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:urlStr toPath:destPath error:&error]
```

But it returns the error "No such file or directory." I have checked and the file is placed correctly in the Inbox folder with its name in Urdu language.

Kindly help.
Best Regards

Comment: Are you sure the error is referring to the file you want to copy? Maybe it is referring to your destPath. You can also test your urlStr using the NSFileManager method - (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path. If it returns YES then your problem in the destPath.

Comment: Yep I have confirmed. Destination path is correct but source does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, paths are of the form `/../.../filename.extension` and file URLs are of the form `file://../.../filename.extension`. When you use `absoluteString`, you will get the same `file://../.../filename.extension` as a string. You should message it `path` instead.

```
NSString *urlStr = [url path];
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, You are right. But i forgot to tell you one thing, that is I am modifying the absoluteURL so that it is correct path because i did not know about path method. I have tested it for non-unicode files and it works perfectly. Regards

Comment: What I can guess it that the file contains a space. So when the ios copies the file on disk, it stores the file with actual name but in path, it replaces space with %20. I tried replacing %20 with space but it did not work.

Comment: Deepak, I did not check this thing but tell me one thing. Should we have separate implementation for unicode file names and normal file names? Can same code handle both types of file names?